# Does being the victim of retaliatory downvoting affect eligibility for Curious?

Tags: discussion, badges

Does being the subject of serial downvoting or other retaliatory downvoting affect eligibility for the Curious badge?

I've been subject to serial downvoting in the past, by someone smart enough to avoid the serial downvoting detection script, and I'm wondering if that affected my eligibility for the badge. I only earnt it today, whereas most users were awarded it when it was created.

I acknowledge I've asked some questions that were downvoted, closed, or deleted, so that may have affected my eligibility for the badge.

Comment: @pnuts On Dec 22, I flagged "I've been serially downvoted, but with a small enough number of downvotes to avoid the automatic detection script.", and it got described as "helpful". Also, I've complained about retaliatory downvoting at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10726371#10726371 and told by HippieTrail not to worry about it, rather than it didn't happen. But ultimately, it's the moderators who have evidence of what happened, not me.

Comment: @pnuts: diamond mods have access to the about  the same information that you see on your own user page, and more.

Comment: @pnuts I'm a moderator on another site, and I can confirm that mods cannot see who cast an individual vote. In cases where serial downvoting seems likely, we can identify the users involved and get _some_ information about the suspicious voting behavior, but never as detailed as showing who voted on what. FWIW I'm fairly certain that what Andrew described above is _not_ a confirmation that he was subject to serial downvoting, just a typical noncommittal moderator response to a flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the system caught and invalidated those votes, then it's as if the votes didn't happen as far as the score and up / down vote counts are concerned. Invalidated votes still *technically* stay in the system, but they exist only as a paper trail showing that a pattern was acted upon.

It's *excruciatingly* difficult to evade the vote detection algorithm, however in cases where that *might* have happened, someone with developer access is going to need to analyze the votes that you've received, and *possibly* invalidate some of them manually. If you think that *extremely* carefully targeted votes might be holding you back from the badge, [contact us](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact) and we'll have someone take a look at it. However, be prepared for a response that says there's no targeted voting patterns to speak of.

*Most* of the time that you receive what you'd consider to be odd down-votes, it's usually coming from more than one user. This could be due to someone sharing a link to your post in chat, twitter, etc - and several people didn't receive it well.

Just keep doing your best to ask good questions. If you are *really* convinced that something shady held back from your progress, we'll of course look into it, but (I'd say) 8.5 / 10 times, there's nothing there.